# SQLITE3 PYTHON проблема в выводе из двух таблиц по условию

Tags: python, sqlite3

не могу понять как написать условие вывода из таблиц.
Условие такое: выведите кафедры, которые читают более 5
дисциплин.

[image: Схема таблиц]

Кода приложить не могу, так как совсем не понимаю как, в инете ничего особо не нашёл

Comment: Прежде чем отбирать по условию, надо данные для этого условия получить. Т.е. посчитать, сколько дисциплин читает каждая кафедра.

Comment: `select Кафедра.Название from Кафедра left join Дисциплина on Кафедра.ID дисциплины = Дисциплина.id group by Кафедра. id having count(Дисциплина.id) > 5`